# Adjust size for multiple Android Tablet screens not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I have read through the [screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) section on Android and have looked at other posts on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me...

I am using Cordova 2.9.0, JavaScript, HTML and CSS to create this app.

I have tried changing the AndroidManifest.XML by adding the code:

```
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="720"/>
```

I have also tried changing the main.xml code under res -> layout too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, ShowMeWhere"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what the page looks like in the Android emulator:
[image]

And this is what I want it too look like (display the full image):
[image]

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution, but it doesn't look great as the images are pixelated..

[image]

I did this by putting all the image references into `<div>`'s then using CSS to set `max-height` and `max-width` to each of the `<div>`'s.

HTML code:

CSS code:

```
.leftImage{
    margin-left:5%;
    max-width:45%;
    max-height:65%;
}

.leftImage img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```